# sh shell double if statement

Tags: bash, if-statement, sh

Can anyone see what I did wrong here? I keep getting the following error message: [[: not found

```
read INPUT
if [[ "$INPUT" -ge 1 ]] && [[ "$INPUT" -le 10 ]]; then
  Do something
else
  printf "Please enter a value between 1 and 10"
fi
```

Answer (score 6):

`[[` is not available in scripts which start with `#!/bin/sh`, or which are started with `sh yourscript`. Start your script with `#!/bin/bash` if you want to use it.

See also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices#Choose_Your_Shell

---

If you *are* going to use bash, by the way, there's a better syntax for numeric comparisons:

```
if (( input >= 1 && input <= 10 )); then ...
```

Note that lower-case variable names are preferred for local use -- all-upper-case names are reserved for environment variables and shell builtins.

---

If you're *not* going to use bash, use the POSIX test operator:

```
if [ "$input" -ge 1 ] && [ "$input" -le 10 ]; then ...
```

Note that when using `[ ]` correct quoting is essential, whereas with `[[ ]]` it is often superfluous; also, `[ ]` is missing some extensions such as pattern-matching and regular-expression operators.

Comment: Ok, then I need a solution for both as the script must be able to run under sh and bash

Comment: @Atomiklan, then use `[ ]`, not `[[ ]]`. Bash is a true superset of POSIX sh, so if you write to the standard, your script will be guaranteed to work on bash.

Comment: What is the difference between [ ] and [[ ]]?

Comment: @Atomiklan, a full rundown of the differences is available in BashFAQ #31: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031

Answer (score 1):

It's complicated:

First, there are three separate ways of constructing your `if` statement. Each way has its own unique syntax on how to join two booleans. (Actually, there are four ways since one way allows you to use list operators).

#### A little background...

The `if` command is a *compound command* built into the shell. The `if` command executes the commands following the `if`. If that command returns a zero value, the `if` statement is considered *true* and the *then* clause executes. Otherwise, if it exists, the *else* clause will execute. Remember, the `if` is just a command. You can do things like this:

```
if ! mv "$foo" "$bar"
then
    echo "I can't move $foo to $bar"
    exit 2
fi
```

What we need is a *command* to do some testing for us. If the test succeeds, that *test* command returns an exit code of zero. If not, it returns a non-zero exit code. Then, it could be used with the `if` command!

#### The *test* command (Yes, there's really one!).

The `[` is an alias for the [test](http://man.cx/test) command which was created to allow you to *test* files, strings, and numbers for the `if` statement. (This is now a built in command in Bash, but its roots are actually part of `/bin/test` and `/bin/[`). These are the same:

```
if test "$foo" -eq "$bar"
then
    ...
fi
```

and

```
if [ "$foo" -eq "$bar" ]
then
    ...
fi
```

The *test* command (if you read the manpage has a `-a` And test and a `-o` Or test. You could have done:

```
if [ "$INPUT" -ge 1 -a "$INPUT" -le 10 ]
then
    ....
fi
```

This is a single test statement with three test parameters (`-ge`, `-a`, and `-le`).

#### Using List Operators

This isn't the only way to do a compound boolean test. The Bash shell has two *list operators*: `&&` and `||`. The list operators go in between two commands. If you use `&&` and the left hand command returns a non-zero exit code, the right hand command is not executed, and the entire list returns the exit value of the left-hand command. If you use `||`, and the left hand command succeeds, the right hand command is not executed, and the entire list returns a zero exit value. If the first command returns a non-zero exit value, the right-hand command is executed, and the entire list returns the exit value of the right-hand command.

That's why you can do things like this:

```
[ $bar -eq 0 ] || echo "Bar doesn't have a zero value"!
```

Since `[ ... ]` is just a command that returns a zero or non-zero value, we can use these list operators as part of our test:

```
if [ "$INPUT" -ge 1 ] && [ "$INPUT" -le 10 ]
then
   ...
fi
```

Note that this is two separate tests and are separated by a `&&` list operator.

#### Bash's Special `[[` compound command

In Kornshell, Zsh, and Bash, there are special compound commands for testing. These are the double square brackets. They appear to be just like the single square brackets command, but because they're compound commands, parsing is affected.

For example:

```
foo="This has white space"
bar=""   #No value
if [ ! $foo = $bar ]   # Doesn't work!
then
```

The shell expands `$foo` and `$bar` and the test will become:

```
if [ This has white space = ]
```

which just doesn't work. However,

```
if [[ $foo != $bar ]]
```

works fine because of special parsing rules. The double brackets allow you to use parentheses for grouping and `&&` and `||` as boolean operators. Thus:

```
if [[ $INPUT -ge 1 && $INPUT -le 10 ]]
then
   ...
fi
```

Note that the `&&` appears *inside* a single set of double square brackets. (Note there's no need for quotation marks)

#### Mathematical Boolean Expression

Bash has built in mathematical processing including mathematical boolean expressions. If you put something between double parentheses, Bash will evaluate it mathematically:

```
if (( $INPUT >= 1 && $INPUT <= 10 ))
then
   ...
fi
```

In this case, `(( $INPUT >= 1 && $INPUT <= 10 ))` is evaluated. If `$INPUT` is between 1 and 10 inclusively, the mathematical expression will evaluate as *true* (zero exit code), and thus the `then` clause will be executed.

So, you can:

- Use the original `test` (single square brackets) command and use the `-a` to string together two boolean statements in a single test.
- Use list operators to string together two separate `test` commands (single square brackets).
- Use the newer compound test command (double square brackets) that now include `&&` and `||` as boolean operators, so you have a single compound test.
- Forget about test command and just use mathematical evaluation (double parentheses) to evaluate boolean expressions.

Comment: You can skip ``$`` character inside ``(( ))``

Answer (score -1):

### Test Constructs Can Vary by Shell

As has been mentioned in other posts, `[[` is a Bash shell keyword that isn't present in the Bourne shell. You can see this from a Bash prompt with:

```
type '[['
[[ is a shell keyword
```

In a Bourne shell, you will instead get "command not found."

### Be More Portable: Use the `-a` Test Operator

A more portable construct is to use the `-a` test operator to join conditions (see `man test` for details). For example:

```
if [ "$INPUT" -ge 1 -a "$INPUT" -le 10 ]; then
    : # do something when both conditions are true
else
    : # do something when either condition is false
fi
```

This will work in every Bourne-compatible shell I've ever used, and on any system that has a `/bin/\[` executable.

Comment: -1: POSIX.2 specifically describes `test -a` as deprecated. It is an XSI extension, rather than a part of the baseline standard, and **NOT** more portable than `[ foo ] && [ bar ]`.

Comment: See in particular: "The XSI extensions specifying the -a and -o binary primaries and the '(' and ')' operators have been marked obsolescent" -- from http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Please identify a real Bourne-compatible shell where the `-a` test operator doesn't function. Otherwise, it meets any reasonable definition of "portable," and reduces the value of your comment to simple bike-shedding.

Comment: Did you follow the link to the standards document? It directly discusses respects in which use of the XSI extensions in question can lead to inaccurate parsing (and, thus, anomalous behavior), particularly when values being tested are `(` or `)`. There need not exist a shell in which a feature is completely nonexistent for there to be shells in which its implementation has surprising corner cases.

Comment: @ToddAJacobs, ...more to the point, the reason `test -a` is marked obsolescent isn't because it *doesn't work at all* in any shell, but because the way `test` parses commands in its presence is ambiguous, and thus its results are ambiguous. To give you an oversimplified example (the real cases that differ between shells are more complicated), consider `a='('; b=')'; [ "$a" = "$b" ]`; now, is it a comparison between `(` and `)`, in which it's false, or is it a grouping expression within which you're having only a single string, such that the operator is implicitly `-n`, so it's true?

Comment: ...in the simple case where you don't support combining operations with `-a` or `-o` there's no need for grouping operators, whereas in the more-than-four-argument cases `test -a` put you in they're active, and you need to disambiguate between `-a` being data to be tested, `-a` being operators, etc. This is the *real* reason for the horrid `"x$foo" = "x$bar"` hackery even when quotes are used: It avoids `(` or `-a` from looking like something meant to be syntax to `test`. Avoiding obsolescent functionality makes that hackery unneeded.